# React Native Flex:1 working but changing the hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, flex4

here above the red component should occupy the entire screen and the button should go to the bottom

```
`<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}> //red component
      <TouchableOpacity //purple component
        style={{
          //   flex: -1,
          width: '100%',
          bottom: 0,
          height: 40,
          backgroundColor: 'purple',
          alignSelf: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text>Add New Note</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
</SafeAreaView>`
```

[The issue screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dICnT.png)

i want the purple touchable opacity to go to the bottom of the screen

Comment: guys i got the solution....by using position: 'absolute' to the TouchableOpacity which makes the positioning easy using bottom and top

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: add `position: 'absolute'` to `TouchableOpacity` style. This will enable component to stick to bottom of the screen, below the bottom safe area.

Option 2: add `flexDirection: 'row'` to `SafeAreaView` style and add `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` `TouchableOpacity` style. This will bring `TouchableOpacity` to the bottom and right above the bottom safe area.